# Convert time interval (ex :hh24:mm-hh24:mm) from a timezone to another (javascript)

Tags: javascript, timezone

How could I easily convert using JavaScript a time interval from a timezone to another ?

**Eg 1 : 04:45-05:15 (hh24:mm-hh24:mm) UTC+1 to UTC+2 -> 05:45-06:15.**

**Eg 2 : Sun:23:30-Mon:03:00 (day:hh24:mm-day:hh24:mm) UTC+1 to UTC+2 -> Mon:00:30-Mon:04:30**

I guess there's a better and simplier way using JavaScript functions than doing it by myself.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are the values involved here? `Date` instances? Strings containing… what exactly…?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString()` to change the timezone of a date object. First you need to convert the date to a timestamp, I don't know how you have your dates stored as you haven't provided code so I will assume the date to be Jan 1st for the example

```
const timestamp = new Date('1 Jan 2019 4:45:00 UTC');
```

Then you need to use `toLocaleString()` to convert to the desired timezone, as you said UTC+2 I will use pass the timezone object `UTC+2` as the timezone parameter with `en-GB` as the language to return in

```
const convertedDate = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-GB', {timezone: 'UTC+2'});
```

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString